# after migrating from PCL to .net standard, debugger does not starts. It deploys but debugging stops, with following xamarin log error

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, .net-standard

Had migrate from PCL to .net standard, by following this video:[Channel 9, PCL to .NET Standard](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-15-Upgrading-to-XamarinForms-to-NET-Standard), i had recently upgraded to **Visual Studio 2017 15.5.2**, i think it is due to Android SDK conflict, but which one??

Xamarin log:

```
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin|Information|0|Xamarin - 4.8.0.753-d15-5+6575bd113
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.AccountManager|Information|0|VS2017 Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|No license found for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Running license sync for iOS
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Not logged in, using iOS Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|No license found for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Running license sync for Android
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Activation.ActivationManager|Information|0|Not logged in, using Android Community
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Hooked up SDB tracing adapter
Xamarin.VisualStudio.TastyPackage|Information|0|Initialization finished
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage|Warning|0|Initializing Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.XamarinAndroidPackage
Xamarin.Inspector|Information|0|Inspector extension loaded
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|Solution loaded: 'Mobi'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProjectFixerRunner|Information|0|running fixup on project 'F:\cellphone\Mobi\Mobi.Android\Mobi.Android.csproj'
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.ContinuousPlayerDeviceProvider|Information|0|Start()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `Android_Accelerated_Nougat`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `Android_Accelerated_x86_Nougat`, the system image does not exists
Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.AndroidVirtualDeviceProvider|Error|0|an error occurred loading avd `Android_ARM_Nougat`, the system image does not exists
Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio.DebugLauncher|Error|0|Controller.Launch ()
Xamarin.VisualStudio.ProgressReport|Error|0|System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x89710015): Unable to start debugging.

The system cannot find the file specified.

   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsDebugger4.LaunchDebugTargets4(UInt32 DebugTargetCount, VsDebugTargetInfo4[] pDebugTargets, VsDebugTargetProcessInfo[] pLaunchResults)
   at Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio.DebugLauncher.StartDebugger(SoftDebuggerSession session, StartInfo startInfo) in E:\A\_work\110\s\src\Debugging.VisualStudio\DebugLauncher.cs:line 49
   at Mono.Debugging.VisualStudio.MonoDebuggerLauncher.StartSession(StartInfo startInfo, SoftDebuggerSession session) in E:\A\_work\110\s\src\Debugging.VisualStudio\MonoDebuggerLauncher.cs:line 29
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.DebugCommandHandler.StartDebugger(IProgressReport progress, IAndroidProjectProperties properties, AndroidDevice device, String package, String activity, Project project) in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\DebugCommandHandler.cs:line 124
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.CommandHandlers.DebugCommandHandler.Execute(DebugCommand command, IProgressReport progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\CommandHandlers\DebugCommandHandler.cs:line 83
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Commands.CommandHandlerBase`1.Execute(TCommand command, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\d\lanes\5409\6575bd11\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio\Commands\CommandHandlerBase.cs:line 62
```

Comment: do you have Latest xamarin update?

Comment: Yes  i have 2.5.0.121934